# Python pandas splitting text and numbers in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 with column name Acc Number as the first column and the data looks like:

```
Acc Number
ASC100.1
MJT122
ASC120.4
XTY111
```

I need to make a new dataframe df2 that will have two columns first having the text part and the second having the numbers so the desired output is:

```
Text    Number 
ASC     100.1
MJT     122
ASC     100.4
XTY     111
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['ASC100.1',
'MJT122',
'ASC120.4',
'XTY111']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col'])

result = df.col.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)
result.columns = ['Text', 'Number']
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  Text Number
0  ASC  100.1
1  MJT    122
2  ASC  120.4
3  XTY    111
```

The pattern `([a-zA-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z]+)`  means match a group of letters: `([a-zA-Z]+)` followed by a group of non letters: `([^a-zA-Z]+)`. A safer alternative will be to use the following regex: `([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+\.?\d+)` assuming the numbers can only have at most one point.

**Further**

1. The documentation on [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in Python.
2. The documentation on [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the str.extract worked, why would the regex be a safer option?

Comment: Because it will match only and only numbers with a possible point among them.