# How to split a column in Pandas when the first number appears

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Name
John5346
Alex7789
Jackie1123
John Smith4567
A.J Doe349
```

I am hoping to get:

```
Name           No
John          5346
Alex          7789
Jackie        1123
John Smith    4567
A.J Doe       349
```

Have tried something like:

```
 df["No"]= df["Name"].str.split(r'[0-9]')
```

for no such luck> Any ideas? Thanks very much

*EDIT*
Updated to include names that have a space or full stop in them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas splitting text and numbers in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290902/python-pandas-splitting-text-and-numbers-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df[["Name", "sep", "No"]] = df["Name"].str.split("(\d)", n=1, expand=True)
df["No"] = df["sep"] + df["No"]
df.drop("sep", inplace=True, axis=1)
```

The essence in here is:

1. to split, keeping the separator - just put separator in square brackets `(\d)`
2. ensure max splits is exactly 1 - `n=1`

Comment: Do different pandas versions behave differently? In my version, your `sep` column contains the number, whereas `No` is empty. Obviously the end result is the same but in my pandas version, you could name the second column `No`, skip step 2, and directly drop the third column.

Comment: @Mr. T - I dare say - they do. I put how it behaves for me - I'm on a bit outdated one, due to IDE limitations

Comment: Ah, sorry. My bad. I tried a similar approach to yours before you posted it, with `df[["JustName", "No", "dummy"]]= df["Name"].str.split('(\d+)', expand=True)`. The `d+` is the difference in behaviour, not the pandas version.